# PHP fwrite not writing some lines

Tags: php

today I encountered a weird behavoir of my logging class.

I use this code to write all logged lines which are stored in the lines array into my logfile.

This does work really good. Except for some cases...

```
$fp = fopen($this->logFile, 'w');
        foreach ($this->lines as $line) {
            fwrite($fp, $line . PHP_EOL);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

I write log messages from many different classes, which access my core to get the central logger instance. They proceed to call one of my short methods (d, v, i, w, c) (Debug, Verbose, Info, Warning, Critical).

So their message will be prefixed, dated and saved into my lines array

Short method 'i'

```
public function i($message) {
    if($this->logLevel <= SimpleLog::Info)
        $this->writeToLog($message, "Info");
}
```

writeToLog

```
    private function writeToLog($message, $prefix = "Debug") {
        array_push($this->lines, "[" . date('H:i:s', time()) . "] [" . $prefix . "] " . $message);
    }
```

The messages to arrive. They are even stored in the lines array when I write them. But on a misterous way, some messages, which are not from the core, are NOT written to the file. They are printed in php just fine when I echo them but not in the file.

I am completely lost rightnow why this is happening.

I am using different namespaces if thats important. But I still wouldn't see a reason why it is not in that file.

What the log should look like: [Echoed Log](https://paste.myvps.ch/uxexojituk.coffeescript)
What it looks like: [Wrote to file log](https://paste.myvps.ch/xepoyeguri.coffeescript)

Comment: `some messages` which looks like what?

Comment: and in future: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `some messages, which are not from the core` tell messages that are not stored in file

Comment: I added 2 logs, the correct "echoed" one and the one wrote to file form the SAME request...

Comment: use a static property for the log entries to avoid issues with multiple instances

Comment: It is a static Variable published over the public static getter getLogger. The Variable holds a reference.

Comment: maybe it's weird too, but did you try the `file_put_contents($this->logFile, implode(PHP_EOL, $this->lines) . PHP_EOL)`? I would check the `$this->lines` with `xdebug_debug_zval`